# Creating collision detectable area within an animated sprite with Corona

Tags: coronasdk, sprite, sprite-sheet

I have a sprite sheet containing frames for a person that correspond to a number of different actions, such as "walk_left", "walk_right", etc... These actions might have a different number of frames but within each action there will only be one certain area of the sprite that I would like to have detect collisions with other objects.

Is there a way to set up a complex body for each of these actions ? Bearing in mind that "walk_left" 's complex body might contain a complex body at different coordinates from "walk_right"

Any help and/or examples would be useful ?

I can provide code if this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do in those cases are actually create several "characters" one for each animation, and then switch them on the fly as needed...

So you have one newSprite with the walk_left animation and with a collision where I want, another walk_right, and so on...

Just keep in mind that using Box2D you will have to move them all at once (Box2D dislike you moving objects suddenly).

If you don't use Box2D and are handling collisions yourself, then just create several collisions on the same object, one for each animation, and use object.getSequence to see what animation is playing, and use the collision you want, maybe something like

```
local currentCollision = object.collision[object.getSequence]
```

Comment: hiya, sorry for delay and thanks for the reply.  Could you please elaborate further on the following point... "Just keep in mind that using Box2D you will have to move them all at once (Box2D dislike you moving objects suddenly)."

Comment: What I mean is that you need to kinda attach all variations to each other, because if you leave the variation you want a (0, 0) for example, and suddenly move it to where you want, you will trigger all sorts of bizarre bugs with Box2D (it don't expect sudden movements like that)

Comment: so I should try to create a different animation per action ("walk-left" = 8 frames, "turn-right" = 3 frames, etc..) then add my complex body shapes to it? (there will only be one per animation stack) then I need to kick all these animations off at once and just switch between them? (toggle their visibility or something like that) - is that what you mean? If im way off please let me know. regards,  Rich

Comment: You don't need to play the animations all the time (in fact doing that waste CPU), what I mean is that you need make all animations move at the same time, so the code to switch animations would be: curanim.isVisible = false; curanim:stop(); newanim.isVisible = true; newanim:play()